# @implement inside .mm not being ran?

Tags: c++, objective-c, growl

I have a C++ file that runs Obj-C stuff also but the Obj-C stuff does not seem to be getting ran (it compiles fine) but I get an error saying that the stuff obj-c is suppose to do (in this case register for growl) did not get ran.

growlwrapper.mm

```
#import "growlwrapper.h"

@implementation GrowlWrapper
- (NSDictionary *) registrationDictionaryForGrowl {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Upload"], GROWL_NOTIFICATIONS_ALL,
            [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Upload"], GROWL_NOTIFICATIONS_DEFAULT
            , nil];
}
@end

void showGrowlMessage(std::string title, std::string desc) {
    std::cout << "[Growl] showGrowlMessage() called." << std::endl;
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [GrowlApplicationBridge setGrowlDelegate: @""];
    [GrowlApplicationBridge
        notifyWithTitle: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:title.c_str()]
        description: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:desc.c_str()]
        notificationName: @"Upload"
        iconData: nil
        priority: 0
        isSticky: YES
        clickContext: nil
    ];
    [pool drain];
}

int main() {
    showGrowlMessage("Hello World!", "This is a test of the growl system");
    return 0;
}
```

growlwrapper.h

```
#ifndef growlwrapper_h
#define growlwrapper_h

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <Growl/Growl.h>

using namespace std;

void showGrowlMessage(std::string title, std::string desc);
int main();

#endif

@interface GrowlWrapper : NSObject <GrowlApplicationBridgeDelegate>

@end
```

Any idea why it is not being ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your growl delegate to an empty string instead of an instance of your `GrowlWrapper` class.

Comment: Growl Delegate is only for click back tracking and processing. It does not have anything to do with registration.

Comment: Not True, it also can provide the registration dictionary.

Comment: ? Hrmmm how can I do this? You said it needs to be attached to the instance of my GrowlWrapper class? What do you mean when you say instance? `- (void)blah`? I am looking at https://github.com/dewind/real-growl and they seem to be passing it to the Data_Struct thingy for Ruby, but I can't do that? Is there something else I can pass it too for C++?